# Black parts on model that arent part of the texture

Tags: texturing, uv, blender-internal-render-engine, texture-painting

Im having a bit of a problem where I want to texture this model but after I added on the hair and outfit these black parts appeared and I dont know if its in maybe the vertex paint or something else but ive spent a good few hours on it and I'm stumped.
[image]

Comment: Hello and welcome. While files, images, and external videos or links may be helpful additions they should not be the only way to obtain information about your issue. Don't make understanding your question rely on downloading a file, watching a video or visiting an external site. Use the builtin tools to upload [images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [gifs](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963), along with thoroughly explaining the problem in written form so it can be indexed and searched for thus helping future visitors with similar issues.

Comment: Ah thank you for the info!! luckily I didn't end up needing yalls help after all I took a break and figured it out on my own

Answer (score 2):

Ended up just needing to fix the normals by going into *Viewport Overlays*, turning on *Face Orientation*, pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>N</kbd> on the faces that were red and then clicking *Recalculate Outside*.